# Best way to do this sort of fuzzy match

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

Below is the sample data

```
library(dplyr)

first <- data.frame(first = c("Board of Accountancy", "Board of Economists", "Board of Cosmetology"))
second <- data.frame(second = c("The State Board of Accountancy", "The state Board of Economists", "The State Board of Contractors"))
third <- data.frame(third = c("Board of Accountancy", "Board of Economists", "Board of Homeopathic Medicine"))
```

I am trying to do the following but it returns 0 rows for merged_df2. I know why.. the board names are not the same. So that is where i need to do a bit of a fuzzy match. I looked up how to do this on ChatGPT but the code given there does not quite work. Any idea on how I would merge all these three

```
 merged_df <- inner_join(first, second, by = "board")
 merged_df2 <- inner_join(merged_df, third, by  = c("board" = "board2"))
```

Desired Result

```
 merged_df2 : "Board of Accountancy", "Board of Economists", "Board of Cosmetology", "Board of Homeopathic Medicine", "The State Board of Contractors"
```

Comment: You could try the `fuzzyjoin` package.

Comment: You can try with `stringdist` package

Comment: @sjri fuzzyjoin uses the stringdist package under the hood, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate how you could use fuzzyjoin:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

stringdist_full_join(first, second, by = c("first" = "second"), max_dist = 15) |>
  mutate(first = ifelse(is.na(first), second, first)) |>  # since the full join introduces NAs to the `first` column, we need to replace the NAs with their value in the `second` column
  stringdist_full_join(third, by = c("first" = "third"), max_dist = 5) |> 
  mutate(first = ifelse(is.na(first), third, first))
```

Output:

```
                           first                         second
1           Board of Accountancy The State Board of Accountancy
2            Board of Economists  The state Board of Economists
3           Board of Cosmetology                           <NA>
4 The State Board of Contractors The State Board of Contractors
5  Board of Homeopathic Medicine                           <NA>
                          third
1          Board of Accountancy
2           Board of Economists
3                          <NA>
4                          <NA>
5 Board of Homeopathic Medicine
```

Notes:

1. There's a variety of different methods included in the fuzzyjoin functions, for judging the distance between two strings. The default is "Optimal string aligment", but there is a variety of other ones, see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringdist/versions/0.9.10/topics/stringdist-metrics)

Comment: what is the |> operator? Could I interchange it with the standard %>% used in dplyr?

Comment: Also I get the following error, Is stringdist_full_join a custom function?

Error in stringdist_full_join(., third, by = c(first = "third"), max_dist = 5) : 
  could not find function "stringdist_full_join"

Comment: Tim |> is the native pipe, introduced in R 4.1 - see https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/the-new-r-pipe/ you can replace it with the magrittr pipe in most cases and it will work the same

Comment: also run `install.packages("fuzzyjoin"); library(fuzzyjoin)`

Comment: now getting the following error 

Error in `dplyr::group_by()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
✖ Column `col` is not found.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Did you reddit the code before running it at all?

Comment: **edit __________________

Comment: Yes but have since moved on to another project. I added a group_by at the beginning and that resolved it